# Jquery Multi Select box Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I have multiple select in my form. I have groups and items in each group.

Countries and major cities in each country.

On selecting country, it shows all major cities which you select.

I am looking for small and fast loading plugin.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about cascading dropdown lists?

Comment: What do you want a plugin to do?

Comment: @andy On selecting country, it shows all major cities which you select.

Comment: Do you use a server side script? Where/how are those countries/cities stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery UI you might find Eric Hynds plugin useful: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 1):

Try the jquery multi col selectbox http://code.google.com/p/jquerymulticolumnselectbox

Answer (score 1):

try this
jQuery Multiple Select Box Plugin
http://code.google.com/p/jquerymultipleselectbox/

Answer (score 0):

Wicket implementation of eric hynds http://tustor-webtest.appspot.com/multiSelect